# What actual git command does `Assume Unchanged` in Eclipse Git run in the background?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When doing `git status` on the command line, git lists modifications:

[image]

and then I go to Eclipse and do `Assume Unchanged` via menu on one of the files listed above:

[image]

and then rerunning `git status` on the command line again, I'm seeing that the file has been (properly) removed from the listed modifications:

[image]

I'm wondering what does this `Assume Unchanged` menu command equates to in terms of Git commands?  What about other choices from that menu (`Untrack` & `Replace with HEAD Revision`)?

Is it possible to see the Git commands running behinds the scene in Eclipse when executing those menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Eclipse** does not delegate to the command line but **uses [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/)** which is a pure Java implementation of Git directly accessing the files in the `.git` folder. You don't need to have the command line Git installed to use Git in Eclipse.

The *Assume Unchanged* Git command line equivalent is:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

See also:

- [Git documentation: `git update-index`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)

Because Eclipse uses the same terms, the Git command line equivalents are easy to find.